# Can't get image next to other image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the Facebook logo next to the photo of the store, but it just doesn't work..

[image]
Here is some of my HTML & CSS code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Menz store</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <img src="images/MenzHeader2.jpg" alt="De logo van Menz"/>
</header>
<table>
    <h1>Locaties van de Men<span class="menz">z</span> store's</h1>
    <tr>
        <th><h3>Stad:</h3></th>
        <th></th>
        <th><h2>Antwerpen</h2></th>
        <th></th>
        <th><h2>Schaarbeek</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Straat:</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Offereande 9 & 71</td>

        <td></td>
        <td>Chaussée de waterloo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</br>
<img src="images/MenzStore.jpg" alt="Menz winkel" class="Menz1"/>

<div id="TwitterAndInsta">
    <!---->
    <a href="https://twitter.com/MenzStore">
        <img src="images/Twitter2.jpg" alt="Logo van twitter" id="twitterLogo">
    </a>
    <a href="http://instagram.com/menzstore">
        <img src="images/instagram.png" alt="Logo van Instagram" id="instagramlogo">
    </a>
</div>
<div id="Facebook">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/menzstore">
        <img src="images/Facebook.jpg" alt="Logo van Facebook"/></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    body {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 18%;
    background: #F2F2F2;
}

header {
    height:305px;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: -10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

table {
    margin-left: 27%;
    width: 400px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
img.menz1 {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
span.menz {
    color: darkblue;
}
div#TwitterAndInsta a img {

    width:250px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -49%;
    margin-top:4444444444444444444%;
    position: fixed;
}

div#TwitterAndInsta a img#twitterLogo {
    margin-top:-43%;

}
div#TwitterAndInsta a img#instagramlogo {
    margin-top: -63%;
}

div#Facebook img {
    height: 250px;
    width:250px;
    margin-right: -20%;
    float: right;
}
```

If you want more information, let me know please :)

Comment: Please share more of your HTML markup; we can't help you unless we know how the above code is working in relation to your other code.

Comment: Hard to tell with only partial code from your page. However, if you remove the "margin-right: -20%" does it help?

Comment: Possible that your other image (`img.menz1`) is not `float`ing? And you image class is `Menz1`, not `menz1`.

Comment: That doesn't help Billy

Comment: And an float didn't help neither putvande

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move #facebook div ABOVE the image, now it's floating right after the image so it ends up below it

it's not clear the expected result anyway, maybe you need some margins or something else

Answer (score 1):

Remove float from your body, and move the facebook image above your main image.

```
    body {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 18%;
    background: #F2F2F2;
}
```

Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/6Pkz5/